# How to send email with Gmail on a EC2 server

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-ec2, gmail

Hello I would like to send a mail from gmail with a EC2 server,
here is my python script :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf­-8 ­-*-

import smtplib

gmail_user = 'libra.corp.services@gmail.com'
gmail_password = 'pwd'

sent_from = gmail_user
to = ['aao2010@hotmail.fr']
subject = 'Value bet'
body = 'Hey, what'

email_text = """\
From: %s
To: %s
Subject: %s

%s
""" % (sent_from, ", ".join(to), subject, body)

try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
    server.ehlo()
    server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
    server.sendmail(sent_from, to, email_text)
    server.close()

    print('Email sent')
except:
    print('Something went wrong...')
```

I indicate my outbound rules on EC2 server :

```
SMTPS              TCP  465 0.0.0.0/0   -
SMTPS              TCP  465 ::/0    -
TCP personnalisé   TCP  587 0.0.0.0/0   -
TCP personnalisé   TCP  587 ::/0    -
```

Plus my gmail account is setting on "Access for less secure apps to On"

Here is the output :

```
Something went wrong...
```

Answer (score 0):

in my own Python app I use the port 587 with TLS, also with `smtplib`. That is my only difference with your setup. Did you also try that? The e-mail sending code would boil down to this:

```py
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
    server.sendmail(sent_from, to, email_text)
    server.close()
```

Comment: I think the problem comes from my outbound rules but I do not know how to solve it

Comment: The 587 rule needs to be _inbound_ also I think

Comment: I applied the 587 rule for inbound It changes nothing